# How to perform resampling in xarray without pandas Grouper error?

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I am trying to resample an xarray DataArray to get the mean values of the array at N-second intervals. My DataArray has two co-ordinates, time and latitude (LAT_GIN), with one dimension: time. A minimal version of this with 100 time points is below:

```
# Create a time coordinate
start_time = pd.Timestamp("2023-09-25 12:34:56")
time_values = pd.date_range(start_time, periods=100, freq="1S")
lat_values = np.random.rand(100).astype(np.float32)
da = xr.DataArray(lat_values, coords={'time': time_values}, dims=['time'])
da.coords['LAT_GIN'] = xr.Variable(('time',), lat_values)
```

To resample every, e.g. 20 seconds, I am using the line:

```
da.resample(time='20S').mean()
```

The output I am expecting is a resampled DataArray with five values (100/20), where the LAT_GIN co-ordinate has also been averaged over each of the ten sample periods.

Instead, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Grouper.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'base'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Pandas 2.1.0. It worked fine in Pandas 1.5.3.

Comment: Could you please report this bug on the xarray issue tracker? So that we can fix it for everyone else in future! https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug%2Cneeds+triage&projects=&template=bugreport.yml

Comment: @ThomasNicholas Sure, not familiar with the process though as not made a bug report on github before. I kept the xarray version the same but changed the pandas version to get this to work. Should I post to the pandas github instead?

Comment: No worries! Just raise it on the xarray github - if it turns out to actually be a problem with Pandas then we will raise it there :)

Answer (score 0):

Split the resampling process into two parts: one for the data itself (da) and another for the LAT_GIN coordinate. Then, they were combined again to obtain the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# Create a time coordinate
start_time = pd.Timestamp("2023-09-25 12:34:56")
time_values = pd.date_range(start_time, periods=100, freq="1S")
lat_values = np.random.rand(100).astype(np.float32)
da = xr.DataArray(lat_values, coords={'time': time_values}, dims=['time'])
da.coords['LAT_GIN'] = xr.Variable(('time',), lat_values)

# Resample
resampled_da = da.resample(time='20S').mean()
resampled_lat = da.coords['LAT_GIN'].resample(time='20S').mean()

# Assign the resampled coordinate back to the DataArray
resampled_da.coords['LAT_GIN'] = resampled_lat
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error on the line `"resampled_da = da.resample(time='20S').mean()`, where the error is `TypeError: Grouper.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'base'`